# Sun training for Sun Certified Java Programmer (SCJP) - classroom or web-based?

Tags: java, scjp

Does anybody has any experience with Sun training?
I wonder if the extra $1000 is justified if I sign up for the classroom training vs. the web-based or cd-rom one?

Any advantages / disadvantages for both trainings?

-Goe

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for recommendations about Java training courses rather than a specific programming problem.  In addition to this, it is primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

The SCJP class is incredibly easy, it is basically a test of your knowledge of the Java syntax and APIs.

The [Bates & Sierra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060) guide should get you through just fine.  You shouldn't need anything else.

Comment: I second that. That book, the Java Language Specification, and the Javadoc for the relevant API classes were all I needed to pass.

Answer (score 3):

I train people to pass the SCJP (I'm SCJP 1.5 + SCBCD and preparing SCJP 1.6 + SCWCD). The Sun courses (and material) are very basic and don't focus on the exam objectives. So my plan & advice is:

1. Save the [objectives](http://www.sun.com/training/catalog/courses/CX-310-065.xml) in [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/), print them or make a tattoo. That's what matters to pass the exam.

   The best book to pass (as stated above) is [Kathy and Bert's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060).

   Obviously, setup a Java SDK + IDE of your choice (I love Eclipse) and start programming examples aimed at the cert.

   The only two webs you'll need are StackOverflow and [JavaRanch](http://www.javaranch.com/) where you can meet Kathy and Bert

   Use a tool to simulate the examination. I use [Enthuware](http://enthuware.com/web/)

   Relax, plan for two months if you're studying after work and pass the exam!

Answer (score 1):

I've never taken any of the Sun training classes, but unless your company is willing to pay for them I'd stick to the traditional [self-study](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/SCJP-Sun-Certified-Programmer-for-Java-6-Study-Guide/Katherine-Sierra/e/9780071591065) books. They should prepare you well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I recommends book [SCJP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060) and free web trainings, like http://famulatus.com/quiz-learning/scjp.html
or http://www.javaranch.com/ or similar

This was "my way";-)